# How to find specific files with partial names using Get-Package

Tags: powershell, scripting

How do I find packages like Mozilla Firefox by only searching a few characters? For example, I want to be able to search 'Fire' and have the installed program appear (Mozilla Firefox).

Current Code:

```
Get-Package -Name -like 'Fire' -AllVersions
```

Comment: You use a wild card: `Get-Package -Name "*Fire*"`. This is using the built-in filter for that cmdlet, but you can also use `Where-Object` for a more robust (*but slower*) solution.

Comment: for previous versions of powershell (before v5.1); you can use `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher | where {$_.DisplayName -match "Fire"}`